# Can not running command to run Code Composer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, code-composer

- Ubuntu Version: 19.10
- Code Composer Version: CCS10.1.0.00010_linux-x64

I'm trying to install the [Code Composer](https://www.ti.com/tool/CCSTUDIO) at Linux. But at README into Code Composer file, say this.

```
Code Composer Studio for Linux README
-----------------------------------------

Please note that use of anti-virus software or a firewall may cause issues
during installation.  McAfee software in particular has been especially
troublesome.  If possible, disable anti-virus and firewall software during
installation.  If not, use of the Offline Installer is strongly recommended.

If you are using an Offline CCS Installer, the tar.gz file in which it is
distributed must first be extracted:

    1. tar xfz CCSxx.x.x.xxxxx_linux-x64.tar.gz 
    2. cd CCSxx.x.x.xxxxx_linux

If you are using the Online/Web installer you need to extract the respective tar file
 
    1. tar xfz CCSxx.x.x.xxxxx_web_linux-x64.tar.gz 

Once extraction has successfully completed, proceed with the installation
steps below.
To install Code Composer Studio:

    1. Execute ccs_setup_xx.x.x.xxxxx.run
    2. Choose where you want to install.
    3. Select the components you wish to install.
```

I extracted the file using the command

```
tar xfz CCS10.1.0.00010_linux-x64.tar.gz -C ../Documents/CodeComposer
```

I navigated to CodeComposer directory and used `ls` to see the files and I saw the file that the readme say to run.
[image]

So I wrote the command

```
ccs_setup_10.1.0.00010.run
```

And appeared this

```
zsh: command not found: ccs_setup_10.1.0.00010.run
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you do `./ccs_setup_10.1.0.00010.run` instead?

`ccs_setup...` is not on your path, so you need to give it a specific relative path so it knows where to look.